Mergesort for singly-linked lists gives correct results but leaks memory
I'm working on an assignment to implement mergesort for singly-linked lists in C++. The merge function needs to merge two sorted lists in-place without creating new nodes. The mergesort function should create a new sorted list without modifying the input list.
My implementation passes all test cases but has a memory leak issue as detected by Valgrind. Here's the relevant code, with an example run in main at the bottom:
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

/* node
   The node type for our linked list.
*/
struct node {
    int value;
    node* next;

    node(int val) : value(val), next(nullptr) {}
    node(int val, node* next) : value(val), next(next) {};
};

/* merge
   Merge the lists given by `left` and `right`, returning the head of the merged
   list (the returned node should either be the head of `left` or the head of
   `right`). The two input lists will always be sorted in ascending order.

   Must run in O(m+n) time where `m` is the length of `left` and `n` is the
   length of `right`.

   Must use O(1) space (i.e., this is an in-place operation); no new nodes 
   may be created.

   NOTE: This function should modify the `next` pointers in the nodes, but NOT
   modify the `value`s. That is, it merges the lists by updating their list
   structure, not by moving values from one list to another.
*/
node* merge(node* left, node* right) {
    if (!left) return right;
    if (!right) return left;

    node* mergedHead = nullptr;
    if (left->value <= right->value) {
        mergedHead = left;
        left = left->next;
    } else {
        mergedHead = right;
        right = right->next;
    }

    node* mergedTail = mergedHead;
    while (left && right) {
        if (left->value <= right->value) {
            mergedTail->next = left;
            left = left->next;
        } else {
            mergedTail->next = right;
            right = right->next;
        }
        mergedTail = mergedTail->next;
    }

    if (left) {
        mergedTail->next = left;
    } else {
        mergedTail->next = right;
    }

    return mergedHead;
}

/* mergesort(input, length)
   Recursively Mergesort the `input` list (whose length is given by `length`),
   returning a new sorted list. 

   Must run in O(n log n) time, where n = `length`.

   Must use O(n) space (returned list is created new). 

   NOTE: The `input` list must not be modified in any way.
*/
node* mergesort(node* input, int length) {
    if (length <= 1) {
        return new node(input->value);
    }

    int mid = length / 2;
    node* left = input;
    node* right = input;
    node* prev = nullptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < mid; ++i) {
        prev = right;
        right = right->next;
    }

    prev->next = nullptr;

    node* sortedLeft = mergesort(left, mid);
    node* sortedRight = mergesort(right, length - mid);

    return merge(sortedLeft, sortedRight);
}

/* mergesort(input)
   Mergesort the list whose head is `input`, returning a new sorted list. This
   function should compute the length of the list, and then pass `input` and
   the length to the two-parameter recursive `mergesort` overload, below.

   Must run in O(n log n) time (but that's because `mergesort(node*,int)`, below
   runs in O(n log n)).

   Must use O(n) space (i.e., the returned list is created new).
*/
node* mergesort(node* input) {
    if (!input) return nullptr;

    int length = 0;
    node* temp = input;
    while (temp) {
        ++length;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return mergesort(input, length);
}

void printlist(node *head) {
    while (head) {
        std::cout << head->value << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main(){
    // Example input: 4->1->3->2
    node *input = new node(4, new node(1, new node(3, new node(2))));
    node *sorted = mergesort(input);
    printlist(sorted); // 1 2 3 4
    return 0;
}

This is what Valgrind reports:

I haven't been able to find where I'm leaking memory. The program returns the correct results for the test cases, but I can't figure out the flaw in my logic in regards to the leakage. What am I missing?

First, this is not a [mcve].  Where is the main function?  What is the test data you are using?  Second, -- but I cant figure out the flaw in my logic --  Use a debugger.  Third, I could not find a single call to delete in what you posted, given that your code has return new node(input->value);.

valgrind says you have allocated memory in make_list function, which is located in file assign3_test.cpp on line 292. That would be the first place to check.

The leaked memory comes from the input lists allocated outside this code. Which would suggest missing cleanup in the test code. But I don't think you have satisfied the "The input list must not be modified in any way." requirement, so maybe fix that first.

@trincot the way I'm reading it, the mergesort function should make one copy of the input ("Must use O(n) space"), merge on the other hand should be in-place and not allocate anything.

Ah yes, the distinction is in the functions. You're right, @teapot418

So that means prev->next = nullptr; is the culprit. The caller loses access to the remainder of the input list and cannot deallocate it.

Aside: the check length <= 1 is wrong, if you call mergesort on a list of length 0 you have undefined behaviour

Actually I would say the error is in the assignment. The comment of the code does not reflect the contract of the API. The given framework is not const correct. Specifically node* input should be a pointer to a const node. With the input being const the compiler would have failed to compile making the mistake in the code obvious.

PS: Why is there no ~node()? Return value should be std::unique_ptr<node>. Copy/move semantic should be defined (at least deleted) too.

The problem is with the following assignment:
prev->next = nullptr;

This mutates the input list. But the assignment said:

The mergesort function should create a new sorted list without modifying the input list.

Through recursion this mutation will eventually isolate every node in the input, so that after you have completed the top-level mergesort call, the input pointer will just point to a node that has no successor. By consequence, the caller has no way to free the memory that is occupied by any other node that belonged to the input list.
The pragmatic way to solve this issue is to undo that mutation before returning (but see further). So change this:
    prev->next = nullptr;

    node* sortedLeft = mergesort(left, mid);
    node* sortedRight = mergesort(right, length - mid);

to this:
    prev->next = nullptr;

    node* sortedLeft = mergesort(left, mid);
    node* sortedRight = mergesort(right, length - mid);

    prev->next = right; // restore!

But as your 2-parameter mergesort function does not depend on checking the end of the given list based on a null pointer, but on the given length only (which is good!), you don't actually need to break the input list at all, and can just omit the use of prev.

Thank you so so much! You saved me incredible amounts of time!!

@MiladKhazani You can see it if you printlist(input) after the sort

It's actually really easy to make a non-mutating mergesort, you pass the one-past-the-end node instead of length: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1496f64b7f39b52d

@trincot - deleted my prior comments. I get that the base case will always be reached on every node, so no need for prev->next = nullptr;. My point was that it should be faster to avoid scanning the left list for mid nodes to split the list and instead have both merge and mergesort return or update pointers to first and ending nodes starting from the base case and be updated as the call chain unwinds by passing counts to merge.

@trincot The answer still works well, thanks. I'm not sure why it was removed. I added the acceptance again. Thank you for the help
